# Scala syntax for lambda functions

Tags: scala

So this compiles:

```
def compress[T](list: List[T]): List[(T, Int)] =
{
    list.zipWithIndex.filter { tuple => (tuple._2 == 0) || (tuple._1 != list(tuple._2 - 1)) }
}
```

This does not compile:

```
def compress[T](list: List[T]): List[(T, Int)] =
{
    list.zipWithIndex.filter { (_._2 == 0) || (_._1 != list(_._2 - 1)) }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`_` does not mean `x`.  Instead, it means "use the next parameter in the parameter list" or "convert this method into a function object", depending on context.  In your case, the second one is nonsense because you want a function of one variable but use `_` three times.

Hint: use `x` or `t`.  Spelling out `tuple` isn't likely to help anyone, and the one-letter versions are as compact as `_`.  Better yet,

```
filter { case (t,i) => (i==0) || (t != list(i-1)) }
```

Comment: I'd always use the `case (x, y)` syntax as well but `t2`, `t3` are good substitutions as well

Answer (score 2):

Your second example expands to:

```
def compress[T](list: List[T]): List[(T, Int)] =
{
    list.zipWithIndex.filter { ((x => x._2) == 0) || ((y => y._1) != list((z => z._2) - 1)) }
}
```

which the compiler rightly rejects as nonsensical.  An call containing `_` expands to a lambda around *just that call*, and nothing else.

Comment: I think the last part is actually `(x => x._2 == 0) || (y => y._1 != list(z => z._2 - 1))`.